# How to attach a module to a drupal article?

Tags: hooks

I have a php function in a drupal module. This function outputs some random text. I want to attach this module to a Drupal article so that each time someone creates an article, random text will appear in it. How can I do this?

Comment: If your module can into rules, do it with rules. Or simply implement hook_node_presave where you can use function from your module (implement it in your random text module).

Comment: but how do I attach the module to the article. Like, make it run whenever a new article is created?

Comment: Oh, u need to read about drupal hooks, module creation. Or just wait for solution here

Comment: What module r u using for random (fish?) text?

Comment: I created my own

Comment: So ib your module you should implement hook_node_presave hook. I will show example later.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but the question is too broad, as it is. Please edit your question adding some details, for example: Where do you want that text to appear? Are you sure you need to attach it before it is saved, and you cannot just show it when the node is shown? Since the question is about code you wrote, we expect to see the code. There are many details that are inside the code, and which could make the answer change; the more details you give, the more helpful the question could be for future users too.

Comment: Downvote was from me. I undid it, because if you will provide info kiamlaluno asked you, you will not deserve it anymore. And if you will not? Well, I hope you will, this question might yet be a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, my module named **custom2**, so:

```
<?php

function custom2_random_text(){
    return 'random-text';
}

function custom2_node_presave($node){
    //check for our node type if needed
    if($node->type == 'article')
        //assign value
        $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = custom2_random_text();
}
```

- hook only works for *Article* content type
- **custom2**_random_text - returns random text
- **custom2**_node_presave - implementation of [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

  > function **hook_node_presave**
  >
  > 7 node.api.php    hook_node_presave($node)
  >
  > Act on a node being inserted or updated.
  >
  > This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the
  >   database.

Note how hooks in Drupal works. You are implementing *hook_node_presave* in your_module.module via replacing *hook* word by your module's name.

If you in doubt about structure of some entity on your site I should recommend you to use [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel).

For first step you can implement [hook_node_view](http://hook_node_view) and in code of your implementation use [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)($node) - it is Devel module function that will display node structure when node is displaying.

For my example:

```
function custom2_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  dpm($node);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your formatting? Upvoted anyway, but you formatted one part as a quote without clearly mentioning what you are quoting there.

Comment: Agree, my mistake, I will change some lines. UPD: did it looks more clearly?

Comment: Thanks. When we are at that - don't mark things like "update 1", "update 2" and so on. Most people will not care and will expect well integrated, consistent answer that's easy to read from beginning to end. Those who care already can see [revision history](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/170326/revisions) so they do not need it anyway :)